# Отсутствует перевод резолюций в группах голосов за восстановление и переоткрытие

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

На вкладке "голоса" вкладки "Активность" профиля нет перевода действий переоткрытия и удаления:

> [image: reopen]

> [image: undelition]

В Transifex слова переведены уже давно, но на сайте остаются непереведенными. Стало быть они захардкожены. Требуется обеспечить возможность локализации.

- [reopen](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265059?key=9159882649a5bf130eab7e82e7ee230c)
- [undeletion](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263687?key=f333421df8d31cad9f7954e81f287514)