# Требуется разделение контекстов для голосов и действий с сообщением

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, локализация, профиль-участника

Недавно был [пофикшен баг](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290422/339911) с локализацией голосов на закрытие и восстановление. При этом обнаружилась другая проблема. Действия под вопросом у нас должны быть [заданы глаголами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3747/176217):

- `поделиться` / `share`
- `править` / `edit`
- `переоткрыть` / `reopen`
- `закрыть` / `close`
- `удалить` / `delete`
- `восстановить` / `undelete`

А голоса в профиле [должны быть существительными](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3612/176217):

- `удаление` / `deletion`
- `восстановление` / `undelete`
- `закрытие` / `closure`
- `переоткрытие` / `reopen`

Можно заметить, что для `reopen` и `undelete` нам нужен разных перевод в разных контекстах. Либо в виде глагола, либо в виде существительного. Возможен ещё вариант замены оригинальных строк: `undelete` на `undeletion` и `reopen` на `reopening` в секции голосов. Но это довольно сомнительная затея, хотя участие знатоков тонкостей английского языка тут бы не помешало.

Возможные пути решения данной проблемы:

- придумать единый перевод для разных контекстов (можем исправить самостоятельно)
- добавить контекст к строкам для перевода (требуется участие разработчиков)
- изменить оригинальные строки (требуется участие ещё большего числа разработчиков, если это вообще возможно)

Если у кого-то есть ещё идеи, предлагайте в форме ответов или комментариев.

Завёл багу на MSE: [Add distinct context for vote tabs for localization purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393539/339911)