# Необходимо улучшить перевод названий действий

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника

В профиле: <kbd>Активность</kbd>, <kbd>все действия</kbd> – <kbd>все</kbd>

Таблица со списком действий, второй столбец — наименование действия, большинство из этих наименований требуют улучшения, как то: **отвечен** (ответ?), **исправлен** (исправление/редактирование?), **задан** (вопрос?) и, особо вопиющий, **награждений** (награждение/получен знак?)

> [image: ошибочная форма награждений]

Comment: Это следствие исправления другого [бага](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305581/339911).

Comment: Ну т.е. это баг, ибо одна и та же строка используется там, где должны использоваться две разных

Comment: Да. Но таких багов хватает по сайту. Первое, что вспоминается, это [вот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4679/176217). Кстати, вижу там и другой баг ("1 года 3 месяца назад") ... вылезает из "участник в течение...".