# Переименовать действие "дан ответ" на "ответил" во вкладке Ответов

Tags: предложение, локализация

На странице участника во вкладке "Реакции/Ответы" название действия "дан ответ" звучит весьма не по-русски, больше по-японски, я бы сказал, поэтому предлагаю заменить на более приятное по звучанию и ясное по пониманию слово "ответил". В таком случае появится связь между 2-м, 3-м и 4-м столбцом: "пользователь" — "ответил" — "заголовок ответа".

Comment: Нет страдательного залога - это плюс. А кто помнит, мы договорились мужской женский род - всё в мужском оформлять?

Comment: Пользователь — это он. Мы же не знаем кто там на самом деле.

Comment: Только не "пользователь", а "участник"  -- так термин было принято перевести, поищите на мете.

Comment: Нет, там не только его ответы, но и ответы на его вопросы.

Comment: Так, стоп. Они ж там все такие.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Необходимо улучшить перевод названий действий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7378/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 0):

Там вообще ответы не самого участника, а чужие на его вопросы. Так что тогда уж "получен ответ" или "отвечен".

Comment: Отвечен — звучит дико, получен ответ — как в ведомстве каком-то.

Comment: Отвечено. Потрачено.

Comment: Там слева пользователь, выполнивший действие, так что «ответил» нормально и похоже на оригинал «answered».

Answer (score -9):

Ответил - это мужской род. Это нарушает права трансгендеров.

Считаю недопустимым такой вариант.

Comment: Полосмешей (trans-gender) тогда уж.