# Переоткрытие в очереди?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Насколько я помню, раньше там было "Переоткрыть". Да и в оригинале инфинитив "Reopen"
https://ru.traducir.win/string/7205

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть некоторые проблемы: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4679/176217

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Заменил на предложенный глагол (всё таки в очереди проверок это, имхо, больше в глаза бросается), но как уже заметил в комментарии, имеется проблема из-за неразделенных контекстов: [Требуется разделение контекстов для голосов и действий с сообщением](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4679/176217)

Если их не разделить, где-то всё равно будет ошибка локализации.