# Рекомендуется закрыть?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

https://ru.traducir.win/string/3592

В оригинале инфинитив. Впрочем, у нас все остальные пункты тоже в инфинитиве. Фраза должна обозначать активное действие. Или, всё же, нет?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вероятно, связанный вопрос: [Переоткрытие в очереди?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9036/15479)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/3592

Предложил:

> Рекомендовать закрытие

Comment: Утвердил перевод

Comment: Русский язык, слишком много букв((